# How to click a Vue/Vuetify card using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using selenium version 4.0.0, for reference.

I'm trying to click a Vuetify card element, which is acting as a button, but I running into an `element not interactable: [object HTMLDivElement] has no size and location` or just `element not interactable` errors. I have been able to solve similar problems with action chains in the past, but it doesn't seem to work with this.

This is the list element the button is contained within:

```
<li class="lu-li list-item" data-v-711d8d7a="" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="addCard v-card v-card--link v-sheet theme--light" data-v-711d8d7a="" tabindex="0" onselectstart="return false;">
        ::before
        <i class="v-icon notranslate btnAdd material-icons theme--light enableIcon" data-v-711d8d7a="" aria-hidden="true">
            add
            ::after
        </i>
    </div>
</li>
```

The first things I tried was simply clicking on the element, and then clicking on the `<i>` element beneath it when that didn't work:

```
addQLButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "addCard")
addQLButton.click()

addQLButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btnAdd")
addQLButton.click()
```

I have already tried using `WebDriverWait` on both the v-card `<div>` and `<i>` element to make sure they are available before being clicked, which it passes without any issues:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "addCard"))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btnAdd"))
```

I have already tried using action chains to make sure the elements are visible (this has worked in the past with similar errors), but I still run into the same issue:

```
addQLButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "addCard")
actions.move_to_element(addQLButton).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", addQLButton)

addQLButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btnAdd")
actions.move_to_element(addQLButton).perform()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", addQLButton)
```

The elements are not in an iframe, and I am sure I have the correct window selected as I am still able to interact with its elements.

I am at a bit of a loss, any help would be much appreciated. I'm happy to answer any clarifying questions if I didn't explain the issue clearly enough.

Comment: What site is it on?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan It's an internal site my company runs, so unfortunately I can't share the whole page. I might be able to give you more information if you have something specific you were looking for

Comment: Try copying its selector from the developer tools and use css selector cause im wondering if you have the right element you are grabbing.

Comment: I've tried it with every element within the container, but I'm still not having any luck. I've also tried selecting by xpath, but that doesn't seem to help either.

I think it might have something to do with the aria-hidden="true" attribute, but I can't figure out how to change it to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with some javascript:

```
js = "document.querySelector('.btnAdd').click();"
driver.execute_script(js)
```